# How to test a customized not_found route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have the following situation:

**EDITED**

In my routes.rb

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
        # the definitions of other routes of my api
        # ...
        match '*path', to: 'unmatch_route#not_found', via: :all
    end
end
```

**EDITED**

My controller:

```
class Api::V1::UnmatchRouteController < Api::V1::ApiController
  def not_found
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: { error: 'not_found' }, status: 404 }
    end
  end
end
```

My test is as shown:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::UnmatchRouteController, type: :controller do
  describe 'get response from unmatched route' do
    before do
      get :not_found, format: :json
    end

    it 'responds with 404 status' do
      expect(response.status).to eq(404)
    end

    it 'check the json response' do
      expect(response.body).to eq('{"error": "not_found"}')
    end
  end
end
```

It seems right to me, however I got the same error for both `it` statments:

```
1) Api::V1::UnmatchRouteController get response from unmatched route responds with 404 status
 Failure/Error: get :not_found, format: :json

 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"not_found", :controller=>"api/v1/unmatch_route", :format=>:json}
 # /home/hohenheim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@dpms-kaefer/gems/gon-6.1.0/lib/gon/spec_helpers.rb:15:in `process'
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/unmatch_route_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**EDITED**

The purpose with this route is be trigged when there's no other route possible in my api, with a custom *json 404 response*. This route and controller is working as expected right now, when we access routes like: `/api/v1/foo` or `/api/v1/bar`

How can I write the tests properly?

Additional info: Rails 4.2.6, Rspec 3.5.4

Comment: have you tried to add as: "not_found" in your route?

Comment: if you mean to write `match '*path', to: 'unmatch_route#not_found', as: 'not_found', via: :all`
I did it now, but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to write routes spec, it won't work too and it will return something strange.

```
 Failure/Error:
       expect(get("/unmatch")).
         to route_to("unmatch_route#not_found")
   The recognized options <{"controller"=>"unmatch_route", "action"=>"not_found", "path"=>"unmatch"}> did not match <{"controller"=>"unmatch_route", "action"=>"not_found"}>, difference:.
   --- expected
   +++ actual
   @@ -1 +1 @@
   -{"controller"=>"unmatch_route", "action"=>"not_found"}
   +{"controller"=>"unmatch_route", "action"=>"not_found", "path"=>"unmatch"}
```

Beside action not_found, it returned path => unmatch that maybe why controller spec didn't work as expected. Thus instead of controller test you can use request test as below.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "get response from unmatched route", :type => :request do
  before do
    get '/not_found', format: :json
  end

  it 'responds with 404 status' do
    expect(response.status).to eq(404)
  end

  it 'check the json response' do
    expect(response.body).to eq('{"error": "not_found"}')
  end
end
```

Comment: I did the route spec as in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Marinofull/c8d750b826ad2f969ea625e8efbb2545) But it only test if there's a matching route, now I'm trying to test the content from the response of that route.

Comment: It worked, thanks! It's not yet a spec controller as I would like, but I'll be flagging this answer as the best for now

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/match

It says:

> Note that :controller, :action and :id are interpreted as url query parameters and thus available through params in an action.
>
> match ":controller/:action/:id"

Your route is:

```
match '*path', to: 'unmatch_route#not_found', via: :all
```

So your test is trying to find a route with :action=>"not_found" inside :controller=>"api/v1/unmatch_route". But your routes.rb does not have this route.

try something like this:

```
match 'unmatch_route/not_found', to: 'unmatch_route#not_found', via: :all
```

If you really need to use *path try this:

```
match '/:path/', :to => 'unmatch_route#not_found', :path=> /.*/, :as =>'not_found'
```

Comment: I tried this, changing `match` by `get` and also appending `, via: :all` at the end of your suggestion and it stopped to redirect me to my custom json. It returns the default **Routing Error** of rails.
And yes, I really need to use *path, in order to match every route witch wasn't matched by the routes written before this line

Comment: Have you tried to run rake routes, and checked what is your route format?

Comment: I've got this `api_v1_not_found        /api/v1/*path(.:format)        api/v1/unmatch_route#not_found {:format=>:json}` for the route `match '*path', to: 'unmatch_route#not_found', as: 'not_found', via: :all`

and: `/api/v1/*path(.:format)        api/v1/unmatch_route#not_found {:format=>:json}` for:
`match '*path', to: 'unmatch_route#not_found', via: :all`

I'm not sure how can I use this information

Comment: Have you tried this: match '/:path/', :to => 'unmatch_route#not_found', :path=> /.*/, :as =>'not_found'  ??

Comment: yes, as I sad before, I tried like this, but it's not possible to use the `match` method without specifying an HTTP method. Then I tried appending `, via: :all` and in another moment just changing the `match` by `get`. And the route stopped to returning my json.

Answer (score 0):

I also found myself wanting to test the response for API errors was rendering JSON, rather than writing a spec which simply rescued `ActionController::RoutingError`.

The following [request spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) worked for me, using Rails 6.0 & RSpec 3.9:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe '404 response for API endpoints' do
  it 'renders an error in JSON' do
    render_exceptions do
      get '/api/v1/fictional-endpoint', headers: { 'Accept' => 'application/json' }
    end

    expect(response).to have_http_status(:not_found)
    expect(response['Content-Type']).to include('application/json')
    expect(json_response.fetch(:errors)).to include('Not found')
  end

  private

  def json_response
    JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
  end

  def render_exceptions
    env_config = Rails.application.env_config
    original_show_exceptions = env_config['action_dispatch.show_exceptions']
    original_show_detailed_exceptions = env_config['action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions']
    env_config['action_dispatch.show_exceptions'] = true
    env_config['action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions'] = false
    yield
  ensure
    env_config['action_dispatch.show_exceptions'] = original_show_exceptions
    env_config['action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions'] = original_show_detailed_exceptions
  end
end
```

References:

- [How to have Rails request specs handling errors like production](https://medium.com/@edgar/rspec-how-to-have-rails-request-specs-handling-errors-like-production-a8c21ed0308a)
- [Comment regarding Rails.application.env_config caching](https://thepugautomatic.com/2014/08/404-with-rails-4/#comment-1714338343)